# Text decorations in CSS

Tags: css, text-decorations

I've just learned how to make a text to blink (`<div style="text-decoration:blink">text</div>`).

How about the other decoration modes such as color changing? Are they available in CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations! You just learned the most useless CSS statement there is.

Comment: Don’t let anything blink!

Comment: Please promess you will never ever use it except on your local server, that run on your localhost ! Please no more 1998's web...

Comment: I wonder why they even bothered adding it to the CSS specs?

Comment: Ahahah right, i forgot marquee

Comment: Why -1 ? Even if this css proprerty is useless, this question isn't.

Comment: Please do not panic, I'm not going to use these proprietes in web design :) I just want to know everything even about such details.

When I put the question, I thought there are more text decorations available within CSS. Well, I was wrong...

However thanks for answers and critics :D

PS: When saying "color changing" I meant automatic changing in random colors.

Comment: automatic changing of random colors can be done with a  set interval thing in javascript, that every time it is called, updates some variable to change the color.

As for blink, it's considerd bad usability, because people can only remember 5-8 things at a time in their working memory, and each time the thing blinks, it pushes one of the other bits out.  It's an old hold over form when we needed to be aware of motion in our peripheral.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing too interesting with text-decoration. A good resource is always the w3:
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_text-decoration.asp

```
h1 {text-decoration:overline}
h2 {text-decoration:line-through}
h3 {text-decoration:underline}
h4 {text-decoration:blink}
```

Regarding your second question - of course. CSS can (and should) be used to style almost anything, though blinking text is an extreme example, most rules are much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, color changing is available in CSS. Use

```
<div style="color:red">foo</div>
```

for example. You probably want to check out a good CSS introduction or the official standard:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Answer (score 1):

The available text-decoration values are:

- blink
- line-through
- none
- overline
- underline

See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the following:

`color: #FFFFFF;` (which would make your text white in color)

`font-weight:bold;`

`text-decoration:underline;`

etc.

You should really Google this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by *color changing* you don’t mean just to set the text color as [`color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/colors.html#propdef-color) does but more complex animations.

There are some experiments like WebKit’s [`-webkit-animation`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-animation), [`-webkit-transform`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-transform) or [`-webkit-transition`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-transition). But those properties are proprietary.

Nowadays such effects are done with the help of JavaScript. There are plenty JavaScript frameworks you can use like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [mootools](http://mootools.net/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/), etc.

Comment: Off topic: Gumbo, can you please accept your nomination for moderator: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/nominations-new-stack-overflow-moderator/35598#35598

Answer (score 0):

No, these are generally programmed using JavaScript.

If you are referring to link color changing on hover, that is done with css.

```
a:link { color: blue; }
a:hover { color: green; }
```

Comment: You can add color, see Patrice's answer

Comment: Yes, but i thought the OP wanted to change the colors like blinking the color back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

There are four currently-supported text decorations. (Blink is no longer supported in most browsers.)

Draws a line over the text

```
h1 {text-decoration:overline;}
```

Draws a line under the text

```
h1 {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Strike through. (Draws a line through the text.)

```
h1 {text-decoration:line-through;}
```

No decoration.

```
h1 {text-decoration:none;}
```

NEVER USE BLINK, it has little browser support, it is useless, and has severe accessibility issues. It was made as a proprietary attribute during the browser wars between IE and Netscape, and most browsers never supported it, IE, who copied it from Netscape, has deprecated it, and Netscape, has been dead for almost 6 years.

(Feel free to correct my little history lesson.)

Answer (score 0):

CSS text-decoration property is used to decorate the text or remove the decoration for the text. CSS text-decoration property is mostly used to set or remove the underlines on the web page.

In many case, when you wish to have no decoration for the text you can simply say text-decoration: none;. That makes the text have no decoration.

See the below example for more understanding

```
h1 {
    text-decoration: overline;
}

h2 {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Reference: http://www.snoopcode.com/css/css-texts